# Apache Spark: Count of records by a specific field in Java RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

**I want to count the different types of records in Java RDD basis a field in the Object.**

I have an Entity class having `name` and `state` as a member variable of the Class. The Entity class looks like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Entity implements Serializable {
    private final String name;
    private final String state;
}
```

I have a javaRDD of Entity Object. I want to **determine how many objects are present for each state** in this RDD.

The current approach that I am using to do this is by using **LongAccumulator**. The idea is to iterate through each record in the RDD, parse the state field, and increment the count of the corresponding accumulator. The code which I have tried so far is:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.util.LongAccumulator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class CountRDD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String applicationName = CountRDD.class.getName();
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(applicationName).setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        javaSparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO");

        Entity entity1 = new Entity("a1", "s1");
        Entity entity2 = new Entity("a2", "s2");
        Entity entity3 = new Entity("a3", "s1");
        Entity entity4 = new Entity("a4", "s2");
        Entity entity5 = new Entity("a5", "s1");
        List<Entity> entityList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        entityList.add(entity1);
        entityList.add(entity2);
        entityList.add(entity3);
        entityList.add(entity4);
        entityList.add(entity5);

        JavaRDD<Entity> entityJavaRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(entityList, 1);
        LongAccumulator s1Accumulator = javaSparkContext.sc().longAccumulator("s1");
        LongAccumulator s2Accumulator = javaSparkContext.sc().longAccumulator("s2");

        entityJavaRDD.foreach(entity -> {
            if (entity != null) {
                String state = entity.getState();
                if ("s1".equalsIgnoreCase(state)) {
                    s1Accumulator.add(1);
                } else if ("s2".equalsIgnoreCase(state)) {
                    s2Accumulator.add(1);
                }
            }
        });
        log.info("Final values for input entity RDD are following");
        log.info("s1Accumulator = {} ", s1Accumulator.value());
        log.info("s2Accumulator = {} ", s2Accumulator.value());
    }
}
```

The above code works and produces this  output `s1Accumulator = 3` and `s2Accumulator = 2`.

The **limitation** of the above code is: We should know all the permissible value of the state before the execution and maintain the corresponding accumulator. This would simply make the code too big for a larger value of the state.

Another approach that I can think of is to create a new Pair RDD of String (state) and Integer (count). Apply the `mapToPair` transformation on the input RDD, and get the count from this newly created RDD.

Any other thought about how can I approach this problem.

Comment: You should use the groupBy method. See the example here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/using-groupby-on-dataframe/

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can `groupBy` on the state field and then call `count` on it, this will give you the count for each state. You don't need accumulators.

As a side note, jobs run with significantly better performance if you avoid lambda functions and use DataFrames (which is `DataSet<Row>`). DataFrames provide better query optimization and code generation capabilities than RDDs and have vectorized (meaning: very fast) functions for most processing use cases.

The DataSet API javadoc has a DataFrame groupBy example in the description: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html

It is preferred to read data as DataFrames to begin with, but you can convert RDDs and JavaRDDs with `SparkSession.createDateFrame`.